# Button not working inside <a> element, gets overridden

Tags: angularjs, html, css, ionic-framework

Whenever I click on the following button:

```
<button class="button button-small button-positive" ng-click="openInboxMessageModal()" href="#">
        Message
</button>
```

inside the `<a>` element, it opens up `#/app/appointment/{{item.id}}"` page and the modal at the same time. I only want to open up the modal, and not the new page. I think an override is taking place. How do fix this?

```
<a class="item item-avatar item-icon-right" ng-href="#/app/appointment/{{item.id}}" ng-repeat="item in selectedAppointments | filter: { status: 'today' } | limitTo:3 | filter: query as today">
    <img ng-src="{{ item.photo }}">
    <h2>{{ item.name }}</h2>
    <p>{ item.time } &bull; {{ item.service }}</p>
    <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i> 
    <div style="padding-top: 0.5em">
        <button class="button button-small button-positive" ng-click="openInboxMessageModal()" href="#">
            Message
        </button>
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Why do you have a href on your button?

Comment: A button with an href attribute? A button within a link? How would that work?

Comment: what you have in your `openInboxMessageModal()` method ?

Comment: To create this effect: http://imgur.com/EC1YyN7

Comment: `openInboxMessageModal()` looks like this: http://pastebin.com/bRq9Azzk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element

The a element may be wrapped around entire paragraphs, lists, tables, and so forth, even entire sections, so long as there is no interactive content within (e.g. buttons or other links). ref: [w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element) SO a button in there is invalid markup